# What is the list chromatic number of $K_{n,n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring, extremal-combinatorics

I am trying to find what the list chromatic number of $K_{n,n}$ is for my homework but I have not been able to do so.

The problem is somewhat analogous to the following: Given $l\in \mathbb Z^+$ what is the first $n$ such that $K_{n,n}$ is not always colorable with $l$-lists.

In my homework we were just asked to prove that such an $n$ exists, this is easy because for $n = \binom{2l}{l}$ we can consider taking the ground set $\{1,\dots,2l\}$ and assign each $l$-subset of it to one vertex on each side. It follows that if this list assignation gave a coloring there would be at least $l+1$ colors used on each side, which is a contradiction as there would be a color used on both sides.

Now, we can see that $K_{n,n}$ is not list colorable if and only if there exists a ground set size $b$ such that there is a covering family consisting of $n$ subsets of $[b]$ of size $b-l$ that covers each $\lfloor b/2 \rfloor$-subset. I am wondering, given $l$ what the best $b$ is but I haven't been very succesful, perhaps I am missing something, I honestly haven't even been able to see if the best $b$ is always $2l$ ( which gives $n=\binom{2l}{l}$).

Thank you kindly and best regards.

Comment: The related problem of finding the smallest $n$ such that any bipartite graph with $n$ vertices is not $\ell$-choosable was investigated by Erdös, and is an open problem according to [here](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~erdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/ListColoringBipartite.html#ezzs). Your problem is different, and it is possible the problem becomes easier when you only look at $K_{n,n}$ instead of general $K_{a,b}$. However, [Wikiepdia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_coloring) discusses lists colorings of $K_{3,3}$ and $K_{4,4}$ wihtout giving specific numbers, so I think it is still hard.

Comment: Thanks, that at least shows that my conjecture is false since  the quoted result implies my $n$ is at most $l^{2}2^{l+2}$, while $\binom{2l}{l} \sim 2^{2l}/\sqrt{\pi l}$

Comment: Oh, and if my problem was closed then at the same time we should be able to obtain much tighter bounds for the problem you cited. This is because if $f(l)$ is the function that Erdos wanted and $g(l)$ is the function in this post then gf(l) \leq f(l) \leq 2g(l)$, so I guess it must be open, unless there are better bounds for the problem investigated by Erdos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the information provided in the comments, this problem is open.

The problem of finding for each $l$ the first graph $K_{g(l),g(l)}$ that is no $l$-list colorable is closely related to finding the first $f(l)$ such that there is a bipartite graph of order $f(l)$ that is not $l$-list colorable.

Clearly one has $g(l) \leq f(l) \leq 2g(l)$.

It follows good bounds on $g(l)$ lead to good bounds on $f(l)$.

The bound [mentioned](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/%7Eerdosproblems/erdos/newproblems/ListColoringBipartite.html#ezzs) is $2^{l-1} < f(l) < l^2 2^{l+2}$